# What is the css pseudo element for the am/pm field in input type=time html element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The am/pm is showing based on the browser the app opens in, i want a one for all solution to make sure it does'nt show up in any of the popular browsers.
Here is my input time field html element that im using:

```html
<input type="time" for="Time" step="60" id="timeInput" class="form-control" style="width: 80%; border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2); border-radius: 2.5px;" required/>
```

Comment: It gets the decision of whether to use 12 or 24 hour format from the system locale. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#appearance)

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but you can use this to select an input time in your css :

```
input[type="time"]{}
```

Comment: That's how you select it, but he wants to know what you put into it to prevent the am/pm indicator from being shown.

Comment: The best is to code the input yourself

Comment: Then say that in the answer.

Comment: Hi @ClémentGaudinière, welcome to stackoverflow.
I see that you are still new, I wanted to share with you that the answers should be posted only when you are sure you well understand the question and have response to it. If you think the question is missing some information or not clear; you can ask for info in comment section or just not reply. As in here : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer 
Thanks